# Divide a table into groups based on an attribute in R

Tags: r, data-mining, import-from-csv

I have a **table(csv file)** where first two attributes are **store** and **dept** and then there are other attributes like Date, Sales etc. The table is as follows:-

```
Store Dept Date Sales Holiday  
1      1    ...  ...   ...  (... means some random value)
1      1    ...  ...   ...  
1      2    ...  ...   ...  
1      2    ...  ...   ...  
1      3    ...  ...   ...  
2      1    ...  ...   ...   
2      1    ...  ...   ...  
2      2    ...  ...   ...   
2      2    ...  ...   ...
```

1. Now first I loaded this file into a train variable:-

   *train<- read.csv("train.csv")*
2. Then, I divided/grouped it based on Store:

   *dataByStore<- split(train, train$Store)*
3. Now, I want to **dataByStore** and divide it as per **department**. So, as a result I will get data of **each department of each store**. I think for this, I will have to initialise an **array** of the size of the number of **stores** eg: dataByStoredept, and for each store *i* do

   dataByStoreByDept[i]<- split(dataByStore[i], dataByStore[i]$Dept)

So, **dataByStoreByDept[i][0]** will contain the first department data of store i and so on. Can anyone tell me the syntax to do this as I don't know how to declare such a 2d array. A short explanation with  few lines of code would suffice.

Do mention if any of my presumptions above are wrong.

**Update:**
For the third step, I want to write a function which should go as follows(Its only the syntax that I don't know):

```
dataByStoreByDept<- array(seq_len(dataByStore)) -------> seq_len(dataByStore) is the number of stores

for(i in seq_len(dataByStore)){
dataByStoreByDept[i]<- split(dataByStore, dataByStore$dept) 
}
```

Comment: Hi -- could you produce a small sample of your data and what you have tried? The "array" you mention is called a list in R-speak, as noted under "Value" in `help("split")`, and starts with an index of 1, not zero.

Comment: @Frank..I mentioned the table structure and the two lines I have written till now in the question itself. I didn't mention the date and other attribute values as it is not important here

Comment: I guess I should have said "stripped-down example" not "sample" data. Here's the standard reference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example It looks like @ChristopherLouden has done this for you in his answer :)

Comment: @Frank...thanks for the link

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Making up some data:

```
df <- data.frame(Store = sample(1:2, 20, replace = TRUE), 
                 Dept  = sample(1:2, 20, replace = TRUE))
```

suppose we want to split the data.frame, `df`, first by `Store` then by `Dept`.  We can do that as follows:

```
lapply(split(df, as.factor(df$Store)), FUN = function(x) split(x, x$Dept))
```

The `split(df, as.factor(df$Store))` part does the first split, by `Store`.  The result of that is a list.  We then use `lapply` to apply `split` on each element of the list created by `split(df, as.factor(df$Store))`.  I put the `split` into a wrapper function so that I could pass the second split factor to `split`.

This will give you a list of lists as you describe.